# HTTPS: Most Complete PHP Test

Tags: php, apache, iis, nginx, https

## Testing For HTTPS

I've seen many *quick and easy* PHP tests for checking if a request is HTTPS or HTTP.

However, most ***fail*** this way or that way.  For example IIS, Nginx, Apache, other Web Servers, behind load-balancers, behind reverse-proxies.

I'm looking for a best practice, portable code, to use in my workgroup.

### Can you suggest any improvements?

Below is what I have (define PROTOCOL as 'https://' or 'http://').

```
<!php
if ( !defined( 'PROTOCOL' ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ) && $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] !== 'off' ) {
        // good in IIS and Apache
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ) ) define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ) define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED' ] ) && false !== strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED' ] ), 'https' ) ) {
        // new standard RFC 7239 - reverse-proxies and load balancers.
        // not widely implimented yet
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PORT' ] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PORT' ] ) ) {
        // Is it port 443? Default Port for HTTPS
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' ] ) && ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' ] ) ) ) {
        // reverse-proxies and load balancers - nginx.
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' ] ) && ( 'https' == strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' ] ) ) ) {
        // reverse-proxies and some load balancers.
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER[ 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO' ] ) && ( 'https' == strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO' ] ) ) ) {
        // reverse-proxies and some load balancers.
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'https://' );
    } else {
        // default to http://
        define( 'PROTOCOL', 'http://' );
    }
}
```

I understand and accept that a person ***could** (with some effort)* use port 443 without SSL. Nonetheless, port 443 is the default HTTPS port.

### What WordPress Does

For discussion, here is what WordPress uses, but it has ***many failures*** (load-balancers, reverse-proxies, etc.).

```
<!php
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }
 
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

On the Official WordPress [Code Referance Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_ssl/), for function **is_ssl()**, is this statement:

> It won’t work for websites behind some load balancers, especially Network Solutions hosted websites. ... For details, read “WordPress is_ssl() doesn’t work behind some load balancers.”
>
> Websites behind load balancers or reverse proxies that support HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO can be fixed by adding the following code to the wp-config.php file, above the require_once call:

```
<!php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

This Page has no mention of:

- `$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' ]` or
- `$_SERVER[ 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO' ]`

However, they are mentioned on many other webpages.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP's perspective the correct way to check should be to check that $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is a non-empty value and is not the string `"off"`.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
}
```

What your code seems to be doing is requiring this value to be either "1" or "on".  However, since the PHP manual implies that this can be any non-empty value (other than "off"), this will fail if it's a non-empty value other than "1" or "on".  In practice this may never happen, but it's good to follow the spec just to be sure.

- SERVER_PORT could be used instead, but there's no reason that would work if HTTPS doesn't.  Also, some server misconfigurations could allow plain HTTP over port 443.
- HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO are not reliable because any client can set these (ie, forge them).
- X_FORWARDED_PROTO is probably an alternative to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and probably has the same issue.

If you are doing the above and still are unable to detect it, then the fault lies outside of PHP, and your server layer is simply not passing on the HTTPS status to you.  There is no 100% reliable method of detecting it otherwise, and most attempts will be nasty hacks.

In particular, if your server receives it as plain HTTP but you have a load balancer/forward proxy doing SSL termination upstream, then you cannot reliably detect whether that is over HTTPS because that information is not available to your local server.  Now, here I would question why you would want to know whether the request came from HTTPS, because the appropriate solution depends on what you're using this information for.  The most reliable solution is just to require HTTPS, blocking all plain HTTP, at this point and then you can assume HTTPS in your app.  Otherwise, perhaps that upstream proxy sets particular HTTP headers which you can read, but then you would have to ensure that no traffic can get directly to your local server without going through the proxy, and the proxy strips off any such headers in incoming requests so they can't be forged.

Comment: "From PHP's perspective" I might agree and yet virtually everyone (as noted, even the WordPress Core Team) says it does not work in portable code across all platforms.  In dozens of tests, the above code does work. Standards are great, in the future when widely implemented.  I cannot assume https and sure it would not work in links running completely under http. Portable code...

Answer (score 0):

Below is a bit improved wordpress function. I have added a condition to check HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header value. So this will work on most of the websites which are hosted behind load balancers/ reverse proxies.

```
/**
 * Detect SSL status
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_ssl() {

    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )
            return true;
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
            return true;
    } 
    elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. But from what I have found so far, it doesn't work if the proxy/load balancer is built on Nginx. Nginx delivers $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on' instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']=='https'